# How do Dedekind's eta function arise while computing the partition function of a compact scalar field over circle?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, path-integral, regularization, functional-determinants

I am following the book String Theory in a nutshell (From Elias Kiritsis). In chapter 4.18, it takes a theory following the action:
$$S=\frac{1}{4\pi l_s^2}\int X\square X\ d\sigma,\tag{4.18.1}$$
$$ \square=\frac{1}{\tau_2}|\tau \partial_1-\partial_2|^2.\tag{4.18.2}$$
And computes the path integral, to do so, it considers the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of $\square$ and computes its determinant. The problem is that I don't know how it gets the determinant it shows in the book; the results on the book are:
$$\lambda_{n,m}=\frac{4\pi^2}{\tau_2}|n\tau-m|^2, \tag{4.18.9} $$
$$\det(\square)=4\pi^2\tau_2\eta(\tau)\bar{\eta}(\bar{\tau}), \tag{4.18.16}$$
$$ \eta(\tau)=e^{\frac{1}{12}\pi i \tau}\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-e^{2\pi i \tau n}\right).\tag{C.10}$$

I got the expression for the eigenvalues, but have no clue about how to get that determinant.

My attemp is expressing the determinant as the product of all the eigenvalues:
$$det(\square)=\prod_{(n,m)\neq (0,0)} \lambda_{n,m}=\prod_{(n,m)\neq (0,0)}\frac{4\pi^2}{\tau_2}(n\tau-m)(n\bar{\tau}-m)=A(\tau)A(\bar{\tau})\quad A(\tau)=\prod_{(n,m)\neq (0,0)}\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\tau_2}}(n\tau-m)$$
And trying to show that $$A(\tau)=2\pi\sqrt{\tau_2}\eta^2(\tau).$$ But I have no clue about how to do it, I have tried expanding the product over $n$ and expressing the result with the integral representation of the $\Gamma$ function to get rid out of one of the products and try to relate something with the $\zeta$ sum to get the $\frac{1}{24}$ factor, but I couldn't get to anything similar to the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eq. (4.18.16) uses [zeta function regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization). Eq. (4.18.16) is derived in somewhat more detail in Ref. 1.

References:

1. P. Ginsparg, *Applied Conformal Field Theory,*  [arXiv:hep-th/9108028](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9108028); p.110 eq.(8.4). Be aware of different normalization conventions.